# Connecting an Arduino ESP32 microcontroller to javafx via PacketSender

Tags: c++, javafx, arduino

We have built a drone controller using C++ and an Arduino ESP32 module. We have achieved connection to a Tello Drone and can control it successfully. However, now we want to connect our controller to a javafx program that receives input and then draws on a canvas in scene builder.

Meanwhile the problem is that we can't seem to connect our controller through PacketSender. We have attached our code, including the previous built that enabled connection with a drone.
The big question is how to send the messages between two programs and initiate our virtual depiction of our drone on a canvas - instead of the actual physical one.

The issue seems to be in case 1, line 190, where we connected controller to actual drone, but now have to write up a new connection somehow.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "AsyncUDP.h"

const char * ssid = "OnePlus 7 Pro";
const char * password = "hej12345";

//Connect button variables (Command)
int inPinLand = 18;
int valLand = 0;

//Ultra sonic sensor variables
#define trigPin 2
#define echoPin 21

//Land button variables (Land)
int inPin = 25;
int val = 0;

//Instantiate specific drone
const char * networkName = "TELLO-59F484";
const char * networkPswd = "";

//IP address to send UDP data to:
// either use the ip address of the server or
// a network broadcast address
const char * udpAddress = "10.60.0.227";
const int udpPort = 7000;
boolean connected = false;

char fromTello[256];

unsigned long timer;

//static const byte glyph[] = { B00010000, B00110100, B00110000, B00110100, B00010000 };
//static PCD8544 lcd;

uint8_t state = 0;

//Controller movement variables
int pitch = 0;
int roll = 0;
int yaw = 0;
int throttle = 0;
char cmd[256];

AsyncUDP udp;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  if (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi Failed");
    while (1) {
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(inPinLand, INPUT);

  //LCD screen initialization
  //lcd.begin(84, 48);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  //pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  //pinMode(BL, OUTPUT);
  //digitalWrite(BL, HIGH);

  if (udp.listen(7000)) {
    Serial.print("UDP Listening on IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    udp.onPacket([](AsyncUDPPacket packet) {
      Serial.print("UDP Packet Type: ");
      Serial.print(packet.isBroadcast()
                       ? "Broadcast"
                       : packet.isMulticast() ? "Multicast" : "Unicast");
      Serial.print(", From: ");
      Serial.print(packet.remoteIP());
      Serial.print(":");
      Serial.print(packet.remotePort());
      Serial.print(", To: ");
      Serial.print(packet.localIP());
      Serial.print(":");
      Serial.print(packet.localPort());
      Serial.print(", Length: ");
      Serial.print(packet.length());
      Serial.print(", Data: ");
      Serial.write(packet.data(), packet.length());
      Serial.println();

      // reply to the client/sender
      packet.printf("Got %u bytes of data", packet.length());
    });
  }

  // Send unicast
  // udp.print("Hello Server!");
  // udp.
}

//WiFi connection function
void connectToWiFi(const char * ssid, const char * pwd) {
  Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi network: " + String(ssid));
  // delete old config
  WiFi.disconnect(true);

  //Initiate connection
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pwd);
  Serial.println("Waiting for WIFI connection...");
}

//Drone connection function
void TelloCommand(char *cmd) {
  //only send data when connected
  if (connected) {
    //Send a packet
    //udp.beginPacket(udpAddress, udpPort); OUTDATED has new name with ASync
    udp.printf(cmd);
    //udp.endPacket(); OUTDATED has new name with ASync
    Serial.printf("Send [%s] to Tello.\n", cmd);
  }
}

void sendMessage(String msg){
  udp.writeTo((const uint8_t *)msg.c_str(), msg.length(),
              IPAddress(169, 254, 107, 16), 4000);
}

void loop() {
  delay(5000);

  // Send broadcast on port 4000
  udp.broadcastTo("Anyone here?", 4000);

  // Serial.println("waiting for udp message...");
  int x = 100;
  int y = 100;
  sendMessage("init " + String(x) + " " + String(y));
}
void loop() {
  long duration, distance;
  val = digitalRead(inPin);  // read input value

  //Ultra sonic sensor
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;

  //LCD screen line 2
  // lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // lcd.print(distance, DEC);

  //State machine that connects the drone to WiFi and the controller
  switch (state)
  {

    case 0:   //Idle not connected
      //LCD screen line 1
      //lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      //lcd.print("Controller");

      if (val == HIGH)
      {
        state = 1;
        connectToWiFi(networkName, networkPswd);
        timer = millis() + 5000;
      }
      break;
    case 1: //Trying to connect
      if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
      {
        Serial.print("Connected to: ");
        Serial.println(networkName);

        udp.begin(WiFi.localIP(), udpPort);
        connected = true;
        TelloCommand("command");
        timer = millis() + 2000;
        state = 2;
      }

      if (millis() > timer)
      {
        state = 0;
      }
      break;

    case 2:   //Connected on ground
      //lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      //lcd.print("Connected ");

      if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
      {
        WiFi.disconnect(true);
        Serial.println("Disconnected");
        state = 0;
      }

      if (distance < 10)
      {
        TelloCommand("takeoff");
        timer = millis() + 1000;
        state = 3;
        Serial.println("takeoff");
      }
      break;

    case 3:   //In air
      //lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      //lcd.print("In air       ");

      if (millis() > timer)
      {
        timer = millis() + 20;
        pitch = map(analogRead(34) - 1890, -2000, 2000, -100, 100);
        roll = map(analogRead(35) - 1910, -2000, 2000, -100, 100);
        throttle = map(analogRead(33) - 1910, -2000, 2000, -100, 100);
        yaw = map(analogRead(32) - 1910, -2000, 2000, -100, 100);

        sprintf(cmd, "rc %d %d %d %d", roll, pitch, throttle, yaw);
        TelloCommand(cmd);
      }

      if (val == HIGH) {
        TelloCommand("land");
        timer = millis() + 1000;
        state = 0;
        Serial.println("land");
      }
      break;
  }
  delay(200);
}
```

Comment: Would it be an option to change the connection to a websocket? That would give you bidirectional communication which both sides can initiate. Or, add a websocket to what you already have, let the drone push information, and paint your virtual depiction in a webpage.